# Skip all new device drivers in `make oldconfig` for Linux kernel

Tags: kernel

When using `make oldconfig` I usually look at new options briefly in case there's something important/useful.

However, on an existing system I couldn't care less about new device drivers for some hardware I obviously do not have. Is there a way to make `make oldconfig` skip all devices drivers?

Comment: FYI, sometimes new drivers are for older hardware (e.g., someone will rewrite the driver for X). Or a driver is split, etc.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/116299/automatically-answer-defaults-when-doing-make-oldconfig-on-a-kernel-tree

Answer (score 1):

When you do `make oldconfig` is shows new options only. You could force everyhing new to No with `yes n | make oldconfig`, but some old configuration could have changed (it used to be yes/no, now there are several numerical options, ...). Better don't do that.

Comment: Safer alternative: `make olddefconfig`. Instead of saying plain no to everything, it takes the default value. I still take the time of going through things manually. There are usually 2-3 interesting questions before it gets to the obscure device drivers, and for the rest you can just keep the <enter> key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is `make allnoconfig` in the current kernel, see Documentation/kbuild/kconfig.txt .

Or, to work around the problem that some entries won't accept "N" you can allow for user input once it gets stuck on a question:

```
$ { while :; do
  for i in `seq 100`; do echo n; done; read n; echo $n; done } | make oldconfig
```

This returns input control to the user every 100 questions.